# How to convert sass file to css in phonegap build?

Tags: cordova, sass, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I am building iOS/Android app using Phonegap.

I need to convert sass to css during build. I had been using gulp in my web-app previously.

Are there any option like gulp to convert scss to css in Phonegap ?

Comment: Did you tried to use a SASS gulp plugin ?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass

Comment: what type of build process you are using now?

Comment: @karthick  cordova build process. cordova build ios.

Comment: thats going to be difficult. If you are familiar with gulp, then may be you can use gulp to process the sass file and then call the cordova build.